# QThread work fine in background, but GUI is freeze?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a app and do something in QThread, the thread can process signal and do something fine, but my gui freeze when the thread is running, that's not i wanted, i don't know why QThread can freeze my window, and i try some others method finally failed, can anyone help me, thanks.

The code look like this:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from pubsub import pub
import time

class Worker(QObject):
    sig_hello = pyqtSignal(str)
    sig_test = pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.count = 0

    def run(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        while True:
            self.count += 1
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print('working do something')
            if time.time() - start_time > 1000:
                break
            if self.count%2 == 1:
                print('signal emited')
                self.sig_test.emit(time.time() )
                self.sig_hello.emit('Hell0')


class WindowA(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.thread = QThread()
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.quit()
        self.worker = None

        self.start_button = QPushButton('测试', clicked=self.onUnitTest, parent=self)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def onUnitTest(self):
        if self.thread.isFinished() :
            #send windowA to windowB
            pub.sendMessage('TOPA', win=self)

class WindowB(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pub.subscribe(self.onUnitTest, topicName='TOPA')
        self.winA = None

    def onUnitTest(self, win):
        #recv windowA and start a thread
        self.winA = win
        self.winA.thread = QThread()
        self.winA.worker = Worker()

        self.winA.thread.started.connect(self.winA.worker.run)
        self.winA.worker.moveToThread(self.winA.thread)
        self.winA.worker.sig_test.connect(self.recv_test)
        self.winA.worker.sig_hello.connect(self.recv_hello)

        self.winA.thread.start()

    def recv_hello(self, ob):
        print('recv hello sig')

    def recv_test(self, ob):
        print('recv test sig')

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        winA = WindowA()
        winB = WindowB()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(winA)
        layout.addWidget(winB)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.resize(400, 300)

app = QApplication([])
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
app.exec()
```

The result is freezed:

> [image: 1]

Comment: any solution here?

Comment: You could try moving the worker to the thread before connecting `self.winA.thread.started` to `self.winA.worker.run`